# Migrating from FileNet P8 4.0 to Alfresco (reading MSAR surface.dat files ?)

Tags: alfresco, data-migration, filenet-p8, ecm, filenet-image-services

I'm currently trying to migrate one of my customer's ECM system from FileNet to Alfresco.

Since they are using Filenet Image Services 4.0 SP4, I cannot take advantage of CMIS (only available from 4.5.x).

According to this blog in more or less similar conditions :

- http://blog.tsgrp.com/2010/08/24/filenet-migration-findings/
- http://blog.tsgrp.com/2010/02/09/migrating-from-filenet-to-documentum-could-openmigrate-possibly-do-that/

The best practice seems to be reading the database to find all documents (data + link to image) :

1. Does anyone know how to achieve that (retrieving the document from system tools) ?
2. Does anyone know how to read directly MSAR surface (.dat) files that already contains all information ?

Comment: Why don't you use existing API such as FileNet Image Services Resource Adapter (ISRA)? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27009991

Comment: This is exactly what I planned to do so far :) and where my researches lead me. But I'm looking for comparison elements to highlight the best choice, and I'm studying all solutions, whithout prejudices.

Comment: Can you not upgrade to a newer version of FileNet, then use CMIS to suck the data out to put in your new Alfresco install?

Comment: I already thought about this option, but this implies new licences ... and additionals overhead. Moreover, from what I red, the data migration cost is not free (in man-days). So it's still an option, but really not the prefered one. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best practice is to use standard FileNet Image Services Resource Adapter (ISRA) if you can.

[Product Documentation for FileNet Image Services Resource Adapter](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27009991)

Answer (score 0):

For content migrations to Alfresco you can use migration-center. You can download a free evaluation copy of migration-center on http://www.migration-center.com/free-evaluation-copy/

Comment: I was already aware of this solution, but my main concern was how to read data from Filenet P8, or even Panagon, more than how to automate Alfresco migration itself